# I want to prove this inequality for integrals for f be nonnegative and decreasing on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be nonnegative and decreasing on $[0,1]$. Prove that for nonnegative $a$ and $b$,

$$\left(1-\left(\dfrac{a-b}{a+b+1}\right)^2 \right)\int_{0}^{1}x^{2a}f(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}x^{2b}f(x)dx \geq \left ( \int_{0}^{1}x^{a+b}f(x)dx\right )^2$$

All what I have tried to do didn't work. Does somebody have any idea or can prove it?

Comment: expand RHS?....